# When $\cos(\theta) = 1/8$ it's easy to show $\theta$ is an irrational angle. Is it algebraic?

Tags: trigonometry, transcendental-numbers, rationality-testing

Along the lines of my lines of my previous question about irrational angles "[$45^\circ$ Rubik's Cube: proving $\arccos ( \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} - \frac{1}{4} )$ is an irrational angle?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1352008/45-circ-rubiks-cube-proving-arccos-frac-sqrt22-frac14)", I was working on a puzzle and I ran into an interesting question about an irrational angle.

Take a puzzle made out of a triangular bipyramid that turns on its vertices:
[image: constellation 6 puzzle]

The piece in the center must be a circle because it gets rotated by an irrational amount after some combination of moves.  Here is the path a point takes after repeatedly turning the purple axis followed by the green axis 90 degrees:
[image: point path after 90L 90R]

The rotation matrix for this operation is
$$\left( \begin{array}{ccc}
\frac{1}{8} & \frac{3}{4} & \frac{3}{8}\sqrt{3} \\
\frac{-3}{4} & \frac{1}{2} & \frac{-1}{4}\sqrt{3} \\
\frac{-3}{8}\sqrt{3} & \frac{-1}{4}\sqrt{3} & \frac{5}{8} \end{array} \right)$$

From there you can find the axis that points are rotating around is $[0, \sqrt{3}/2, -1]$
And the angle $\theta$ they're rotating through is $\arccos{\frac{1}{8}}$.

$\arccos{\frac{1}{8}}$ is approximately $82.819244218541^{\circ}$ and it's an irrational angle because the only rational values that correspond to rational angles for $\cos{\theta}$ are $\{-1, \frac{-1}{2}, 0, \frac{1}{2}, 1\}$.

So what do we know about $\theta = \arccos{\frac{1}{8}}$?  It's irrational angle but is it an algebraic angle?  In general if $\cos \theta$ is rational does that tell us anything (beyond rationality) about $\theta$?

Comment: "because the only rational values that correspond to rational angles for $\cos\theta$ are ..." this is completely false. The rationals are dense in $[-1,1]$, which is the image of $\cos$.

Comment: @hjhjhj57  There are plenty of angles that have rational cosines, but they are not rational multiples of $\pi$.

Comment: @RobertIsrael agreed, but that's not what the OP is saying.

Comment: I think that is exactly what the OP means by "the only rational values that correspond to rational angles".

Comment: OP actually means $\cos(\mathbb{Q}) \cap \mathbb{Q} = \{-1,\frac{-1}{2},0,\frac{1}{2},1\}$ if you reads carefully.

Comment: I see, my bad. ${}$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Gelfond-Schneider theorem says if $a\notin \{0,1\}$ is algebraic and $b$ is algebraic and irrational, then $a^b$ is transcendental.  Apply this to $a = e^{i\pi/180}$, and you find that if $b$ is an irrational algebraic, $\omega = \cos(b^\circ) + i \sin(b^\circ)$ is transcendental.  Then $\cos(b^\circ) = (\omega + \omega^{-1})/2$ and $\sin(b^\circ) = (\omega - \omega^{-1})/(2i)$ are also transcendental.

Comment: Your answer is a bit over my head so I'm going to have to do more reading before I understand it.  Thank you, it's going to take me a while to accept though :-)

Comment: Alright I think I follow the first part. You choose $a = e^{i \pi / 180}$ because it corresponds to $\cos({\frac{\pi}{180}}) + i\sin({\frac{\pi}{180}})$ and $\frac{\pi}{180}$ is a rational angle so $a$ would have to be algebraic.  Then $a^b$ would be $e^{i\pi b / 180}$ which treats $b$ as irrational degrees and establishes the transcendence of $\cos(b^{\circ}) + i\sin(b^{\circ})$.  I don't follow how you eliminated the $i\sin(b^{\circ})$ term though.  How does raising $\omega$ to the $-1$ power do that?

Comment: @BrandonEnright: $(\cos(x) + i \sin(x))(\cos(x) - i \sin(x)) = \cos^2(x) + \sin^2(x) = 1$.

Comment: Got it.  You multiplied the numerator and denominator of $\omega^{-1}$ by $\cos(b^{\circ}) - i\sin(b^{\circ})$ which eliminates the denominator and leaves $\cos(b^{\circ}) - i\sin(b^{\circ})$ in the numerator and then the $i\sin(b^{\circ})$ terms cancel leaving $2\cos(b^{\circ})$ which you fix by dividing by 2.  Whew I understand you answer now!